# How to place a node of a certain shape with one side on a line in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I would like to have an arrow shaped node to be positioned with its tail on the vertical axis of my reference frame.

Here' were I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0) node [below] {$\theta$};
\draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,3) node [left] {$f$};
\draw [->,thick] (1.5,0) node [below] {$t$} -- (1.5,1.5); 
\node [single arrow,draw=none,fill=black!20] at (0,2)  {\tiny{\texttt{Integration interval}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Change the anchor to `west`: `\node[anchor=west,....] at ...`

Comment: @Sigur Why don't you write a proper answer. Pier Paolo: Welcome to TeX.sx!

Comment: Because the solution was so simple. But I'll do then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the default anchor position (`center`) to `west` with the `node` option

```
\node[anchor=west,single arrow,draw=none,fill=black!20]%
at (0,2) {\tiny{\texttt{Integration interval}}} ;
```

[image]